# NSFetchRequest on a specific store

Tags: ios, core-data, persistent-storage

I am starting to use multiple persistent stores with Core Data. For that I wrote the following code:

```
- (NSUInteger)countEntity:(NSString*)entityName
            withPredicate:(NSPredicate*)predicate
                  onStore:(NSString*)configName
{
    NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    if (predicate) [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error=nil;
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName
                                   inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    [request setAffectedStores:
     [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[configurDico objectForKey:configName]
                               objectForKey:@"store"]]];
    NSUInteger count=[context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error]; // PROBLEMATIC LINE.
    return count;
}
```

But I get the following message, on the line PROBLEMATIC LINE un the debugger.

```
2014-12-06 02:56:10.932 TheApp[1501:76002] -[NSURL executeRequest:withContext:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1757df50
```

What am I doing wrong?

For reference I have to say that the following method, almost like the previous one, is working perfectly:

```
- (NSUInteger)countEntity:(NSString*)entityName 
            withPredicate:(NSPredicate*)predicate
{
    NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    if (predicate) [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error=nil;
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName
                                   inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    NSUInteger count=[context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    return count;
}
```

That makes me think, since this is the only line added, I must be using setAffectedStores: the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

Your `context` variable is of the wrong type (NSURL instead of NSManagedObjectContext). Make sure you set up your Core Data stack correctly.

Comment: The context variable is declared with this code:
 NSManagedObjectContext *context;
On top of that the line where the crash happens contains countForFetchRequest and not executeRequest (error message).
This makes it difficult for me to understand.

Comment: Your question edit is not helpful. You should show where exactly you get the context from.

Comment: Here is the code to get the context: context=[self managedObjectContext]; In other words the usual way. Since the second method in my question is working (as mentioned) you can see there is no problem with the context.

Answer (score 1):

In case that may be helpful to someone. Here is the solution I found:

I replaced this code:

```
[request setAffectedStores:
 [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[configurDico objectForKey:configName]
                           objectForKey:@"store"]]];
```

by this other code:

```
NSPersistentStore *theStore=[persistentStoreCoordinator
                             persistentStoreForURL:[[configurDico objectForKey:configName]
                                                    objectForKey:@"store"]];
[request setAffectedStores:[NSArray arrayWithObject:theStore]];
```

The part:

```
[[configurDico objectForKey:configName] objectForKey:@"store"]
```

is an object of type NSURL matching the store I want to use.

It now all works perfectly.